# What is a "large" file for COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING flag?

Tags: .net, winapi

I have an option to specify a `COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING` flag to my file copying method. 
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexa) states:

> The copy operation is performed using unbuffered I/O, bypassing system I/O cache resources. Recommended for very large file transfers.

How large are we talking?

Comment: A good rule of thumb would be in the range of 10% to 20% of system RAM.  When your operation can't fit in the write cache, then caching isn't providing any performance boost, and meanwhile you're ruining performance of every operation that could have used cache because it all got evicted to make room for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided by Ben Voigt:

> A good rule of thumb would be in the range of 10% to 20% of system RAM. When your operation can't fit in the write cache, then caching isn't providing any performance boost, and meanwhile you're ruining performance of every operation that could have used cache because it all got evicted to make room for your data.